# Adding html mouseover function with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to write an html MUD game with javascript.
I try to print a message that shows a picture of the character performing the action when moused over.

Here is my code so far

```
function printMessage(message,char){

$("#messageScreen").append('<p onmouseover="showPicBottom('+char.race+','+char.pic+')" onmouseout="removePic()">'+""+message+"</p>");

}

function showPicBottom(race,pic){
    var pichtml="";
    if (origin=="Human"){
        pichtml='<img src="img/human/'+"Pic ("+pic+")"+'.PNG"/ width="200">';
    }else{
        pichtml='<img src="img/elf/'+"Pic ("+pic+")"+'.PNG"/ width="200">';
    }
    $("#picBottom").append(pichtml);
}
```

I always get "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ','" at the first function. Apparently the way I added those two variables was wrong. I think it's the quotation marks but I haven't found a way. How do I fix it?

Comment: You might benefit from the use of template (backtick) strings

Comment: The complete error message also has the information in which file and on which line the error occurs.

Comment: Why are you not using CSS for the job? In 8 years of professional Javascript development I haven't once had the necessity to attach an event listener on `mouseover`.

Comment: If char.race and char.pic are strings, they probably need to be surrounded by delimiter tokens (like " or '). Maybe test the mouseover with concrete values before replacing them by variables.